# python3-dbg fails to import setproctitle

Tags: debugging

`import setproctitle` using `python3` works, but using `python3-dbg` fails. How can I fix this?

```
$ cat test.py
from setproctitle import setproctitle
setproctitle('test')
$ python3 ./test.py
$ python3-dbg ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setproctitle import setproctitle
ImportError: No module named 'setproctitle'
```

I installed setproctitle on this Ubuntu 14.04 system using `sudo pip3 install setproctitle`. I know of a ubuntu package *setproctitle-dbg*, but there does not seem to be a python3 equivalent for this:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade setproctitle-dbg
Downloading/unpacking setproctitle-dbg
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement setproctitle-dbg
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for setproctitle-dbg
Storing debug log for failure in /home/oleg/.pip/pip.log
```

The `sys.path` output of `python3-dbg` and `python3` matches exactly, and other imports seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing `python3-setproctitle-dbg` from source.

1. Downloaded and extract the source from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-setproctitle/1.1.8-1
2. CD to the directory and build it with `sudo make build PYTHON=python3-dbg PYCONFIG=python3-dbg-config`
3. copy `./build/lib.3/setproctitle.cpython-34dm.so` to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` and set the appropriate permissions